# Fallo en la aparición de Eventos, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, eventos

Estoy usando un compactCalendarView para mostrar eventos en mi aplicación. La aplicación llama a una base de datos para obtener fechas y en teoría luego las tendría que mostrar en forma de eventos en el calendario. El problema está en que una vez que obtengo la fecha en forma de variable del tipo Long (necesaria para la creación de eventos), el programa parece no reconocerla.

El método que utilizo para rellenar un ArrayList con todos los resultados de fechas posibles es el siguiente:

```
public ArrayList<Long> mostrarEventos (){
    i = getIntent();
    String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");
    final ArrayList<Long> arrayEventos = new ArrayList<>();
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener =  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String fechaAux;
                for(int x=0; x<jsonArray.length(); x++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                    fechaAux = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                    arrayFechas = new ArrayList<>();
                    arrayFechas.add(fechaAux);
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }
            if(!arrayFechas.isEmpty()){
                for (int x = 0; x<arrayFechas.size(); x++){
                    try {
                        long epoch = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(arrayFechas.get(x)).getTime();
                        arrayEventos.add(epoch);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    FechasRequest fechasRequest = new FechasRequest(username, password, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(fechasRequest);
    return arrayEventos;
}
```

Para rellenar el calendario, en el método onCreate tengo lo siguiente:

```
compactCalendar = findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
    compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);
    arrayCodigosFechas = mostrarEventos();

    for(int x = 0; x<arrayCodigosFechas.size(); x++){
        Event ev1 = new Event(Color.RED, arrayCodigosFechas.get(x));
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1, true);
    }
```

Sin embargo no me muestra nada. He cambiado mi base de datos en local para que todas las fechas sean la del 15 de noviembre de 2017 (para hacer pruebas), y en un convertidor de internet para fechas me dice que esa fecha corresponde al siguiente número: 1510704000000.

Haciendo que me muestre un mensaje con el primer elemento del arrayEventos

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("" + arrayEventos.get(0))
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create().show();
```

Me muestra en pantalla lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es el mismo número que el que debería mostrarme para el 15 de noviembre.

Si lo introduzco yo manualmente, el evento se añade. Es decir, que si yo hago:

```
Event ev1 = new Event(Color.GREEN, 1510704000000L);
    compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1, true);
```

En el calendario se añade el evento. ¿Alguna idea de porqué no funciona añadiéndolo desde el array y el bucle y sin embargo sí que funciona si lo añado yo manualmente?

(Editado)

Al intentar poner un Log para ver cómo se rellena el array me sale lo siguiente:

```
11-17 12:08:52.230 8648-8648/com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba, PID: 8648

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba/com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4519)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                                        at com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                                        at com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                                        at com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4519) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

El log lo puse en el onCreate de la siguiente manera:

```
Log.i(String.valueOf(arrayCodigosFechas), "array");
```

Parece ser que el array no me lo rellena correctamente. ¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Pongo lo siguiente para demostrar que la variable arrayFechas se rellena con los datos que devuelve el response:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(arrayFechas.get(x))
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                            .create().show();
```

(Sólo muestra una fecha por lo que ya dije, en mi base de datos todas las fechas son las mismas por motivos de pruebas)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Editado a raíz de las respuestas recibidas)

A base de poner el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
for (Long member : arrayEventos){
        Log.i("MEMBER NAME : ", String.valueOf(member));
    }
```

Para comprobar dónde se rellena el array y dónde no, me he dado cuenta de que el arrayEventos del método puesto más arriba se rellena perfectamente dentro del bloque onResponse. Sin embargo, una vez fuera de él, el array continúa vacío, es decir, el return por alguna razón ignora todo lo hecho en el onResponse y devuelve un array vacío. Ahí es donde yo veo el fallo, otra cosa es saber cómo solucionarlo, por eso acudo a vosotros. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Buenas @G. Corporales, consulta la creacion manual que haces de tu evento te funcion con "1510704000000L" sin la "L" al final? eso lo consulto por que en el mensaje nos muestra el numero sin esta

Comment: La L es para convertirlo a Long, que es el tipo de dato que reconoce. Si le quito la L dice que es un número entero demasiado largo, y me da fallo.

Comment: ya veo, ok seguiré probando para ver si puedo encontrar la diferencia.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el mensaje de error que imprime en el log.

Comment: En el log no muestra ningún error, es como si simplemente ignorara esa parte del código. Por todo lo demás la aplicación funciona perfectamente, sólo esa parte no funciona como debería pero no me da fallo ni me salta excepción de ningún tipo.

Comment: Añade logs en tu código, para ver por donde pasa, lo mismo `arrayFechas` no se rellena correctamente

Comment: Editada la pregunta para mostrar los nuevos fallos.

Comment: para imprimir un array mejor usa `for (String member : members){
    Log.i("Member name: ", member);
}` ya que se debe recorrer el array es solo por eso el error que te emite

Comment: No se muestra nada en el Logcat ahora. Nada que se llame Member name, ni ninguna información del Log. Lo he adaptado de la siguiente forma: `for (Long member : arrayCodigosFechas){
            Log.i("MEMBER NAME : ", String.valueOf(member));
        }`

Comment: Reemplaza el dialog por un Log.d("fecha", arrayFechas.get(x)) y ve que si muestra mas de una en el logcat.

Comment: Me devuelve lo mismo: `D/fecha: 2017-11-15`

Comment: podrias poner un punto de parada aqui `for(int x = 0; x<arrayCodigosFechas.size(); x++)` y ver que contiene `arrayCodigosFechas` en la linea `arrayCodigosFechas = mostrarEventos();`   ya que es este el que realmente se carga en el event.

Comment: Nunca he entendido de qué sirven los puntos de parada en Android Studio, los pongo y no veo ningún cambio tangible. ¿Algún lugar en concreto en el que tenga que fijarme para ver lo que me estás pidiendo?

Comment: @Nicethunder he puesto el punto de interrupción y he creado un Log como me han dicho más arriba, `for (Long member : arrayCodigosFechas){
            Log.i("MEMBER NAME : ", String.valueOf(member));
        }, 
sin embargo no me muestra nada en el Logcat. ¿Puede significar que el array no se carga? Si es así, ¿Cómo podría cambiar mi método para que sí lo haga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he resuelto. En lugar de hacer el siguiente bucle for en el método onCreate:

```
for(int x = 0; x<arrayCodigosFechas.size(); x++){
    Event ev1 = new Event(Color.RED, arrayCodigosFechas.get(x));
    compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1, true);
}
```

Sencillamente lo he introducido dentro del método mostrarEventos, modificándolo para que no retornara nada y llamándolo dentro del onCreate. El método mostrarEventos se queda como sigue:

```
public void mostrarEventos (){
    i = getIntent();
    String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener =  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String fechaAux;
                for(int x=0; x<jsonArray.length(); x++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                    fechaAux = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                    arrayFechas.add(fechaAux);
                    Log.d("fecha", arrayFechas.get(x));
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }
            if(!arrayFechas.isEmpty()){
                for (int x = 0; x<arrayFechas.size(); x++){
                    try {
                        long epoch = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(arrayFechas.get(x)).getTime();
                        arrayEventos.add(epoch);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                for(int x = 0; x<arrayEventos.size(); x++){
                    Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLUE, arrayEventos.get(x));
                    compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1, true);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    FechasRequest fechasRequest = new FechasRequest(username, password, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(fechasRequest);
}
```

Y sale como esperado. ¡Muchas gracias a @Nicethunder y a @Einer por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Estas inicializando la variable `arrayFechas` en cada iteracion en el primer blucle `for`:

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String fechaAux;
                for(int x=0; x<jsonArray.length(); x++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                    fechaAux = jsonObject.getString("fecha");

                     //=========================================
                     // no deberias de inicializar el array ya que siempre se sobre escribira la instancia sin elementos
                     //=========================================
                    arrayFechas = new ArrayList<>();
                    arrayFechas.add(fechaAux);
                }
            //...
```

Intenta eliminando la inicializacion:

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {
             // Inicializas la variable  arrayFechas
             arrayFechas = new ArrayList<>();

            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String fechaAux;
                for(int x=0; x<jsonArray.length(); x++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                    fechaAux = jsonObject.getString("fecha");

                     //=========================================
                     // Ahora por cada iteracion agregara la fecha al arrayList
                     //=========================================
                    arrayFechas.add(fechaAux);
                }
            //...
```

Comment: Me da el siguiente error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference` en la línea `arrayFechas.add(fechaAux);` ¿Debería inicializar el array fuera del for?

Comment: Uumm. Pense que lo habias inicializando antes de utilizarlo en el metodo. Mira la respuesta actualizada

Comment: Vale, ahora no me sale ningún error, pero sigue sin mostrarme los eventos ni el Log en el Logcat

Comment: Puedes confirmar que la variable `response` si tiene valor y que se le estan agregado elementos la variable `arrayFechas`?

Comment: Si, se ven. Te lo muestro en la pregunta para que veas lo que me devuelve